# grails SchwartzJob with exceuteUpdate is not working

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to run the JOb queue in the table where I see the how many jobs are running and queued. If no job is running, then I update that jobs status as running. I run the analysis and update status to "Done"

```
 def qjobs = Inputparams.createCriteria()


        def qresult = qjobs.list {
            eq("status", "queued")
        }

        def qjobs2 = Inputparams.createCriteria()


        def rjobs = qjobs2.list {
            eq("status", "running")
        }
```

And to update the status :

```
 def runuuid22= Inputparams.executeUpdate("update Inputparams b set b.status = :status"+
                    " where b.uuid = :uuid",
                    [status:"running",uuid:uuid])

            println("runuuid22 is "+runuuid22)
```

The above two commands run perfectly and also the same with status done works too. But query with running doesn't update and it doesn't give any error also.

Whn I check mysql database, it shows lot of processes with sleep status ..

Thanks

Comment: Is your executeUpdate in a transaction? What is the transaction isolation set to? Have you flushed the session after running the update? What version of grails/gorm/etc. Need more info.

Comment: | Grails Version: 3.3.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_241..Yes executeUpdate in to transactional service. How do you flsuh the sesion in grails.. Do we need to do that exclusively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating over a set, maybe try to separate each run with a new trasaction? Please check out this code:

```
try{
    Inputparams.withNewTransaction{
        Inputparams inputParams = Inputparams.findByUuid(uuid)
        inputParams.status = "running"
        inputParams.save()
    }
catch(ex){
    log.error ex
}
```